# How to change table (adding rowspan/colspan) with dynamically generated rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, rows

I have a table created automatically from data in database.

```
var rows  = "";
    rows += "<tr class='row_primary'>";
        rows += "<td>COL 1</td>";
        rows += "<td>COL 2</td>";
        rows += "<td>COL 3</td>";
    rows += "</tr>";



    $.each(data.db_values, function(i, results){     //This is from database with n rows depend on n results
        rows += "<tr class='row_secondary'>";
            rows += "<td>COL 1</td>";
            rows += "<td>results.ID</td>";
            rows += "<td>COL 3</td>";
        rows += "</tr>";
    });

 $('#t_barang tbody').append(rows);
```

My idea is to adding rowspan after the table is created. But, it seems not working as it should be. I tried adding `$('#t_barang tbody tr').attr('rowspan', '5');` for a 5 row table. But, it is not change the table.

current result:

```
COL1  COL2   COL3
COL1  DATA1  COL3
COL1  DATA2  COL3
COL1  DATA3  COL3
COL1  DATA4  COL3
```

Expected result:

```
       COL2   
       DATA1  
  COL1 DATA2 COL3
       DATA3  
       DATA4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume u already know you database data `length` from the first time windows loaded. so u can do `rowspan` before you append your dynamic data to your `table`, so it will look like this in your js:

I asume you have database with 5 data provided:

```
database = [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2},
        {id: 3},
        {id: 4},
        {id: 5},
    ];
```

then your rows will declare for the first time like this:

```
var rows  = "";
rows += "<tr class='row_primary'>";
    rows += "<td rowspan="+(database.length+1)+">COL 1</td>";
    rows += "<td>COL 2</td>";
    rows += "<td rowspan="+(database.length+1)+">COL 3</td>";
rows += "</tr>";
```

the rowspan are init here base on your database length + 1 (for your table header). then you can loop your data like this:

```
 $.each(database, function(i, results){ 
    rows += "<tr class='row_secondary'>";
        // rows += "<td>COL 1</td>";
        rows += "<td>"+results.id+"</td>";
        // rows += "<td>COL 3</td>";
    rows += "</tr>";
});
```

since you already init the `rowspan` you dont need to add the `COL 1` and `COL 2` to the `rows` , so I comment it.

for the record I already test this code and works well so let me know it you need something more.